# The test tool locust.io always show RPS (request per second) 0 if the actual RPS is < 0.1

Tags: python, testing, locust, stress-testing

When the HTTP response time is large and the resulting actual RPS is 0.0x something. https://locust.io/ always shows RPS 0 and now data on the graph.

Comment: RPS less than 1? It doesn't make sense. Please explain more about your problem.

Comment: This RPS is the observed result in Locust. For example, we can launch 20 concurrent virtual users and try to setup some dummy API on the non-async server to respond to this request in 10s and this server process requests one by one. In this case, the response time of one request is about 10s. So the resulting RPS will be 0.1 shown on the Locust dashboard. So the issue I encountered is that the locust dashboard will not correctly show any RPS that reflects too long HTTP response time (roughly over 100s).

Comment: The RPS graph cant really handle less than one request per time span (I think it is 5 or 10 seconds). That might be your issue.